# Ratio of error norms or norm of error ratio in adaptive step size control?

Tags: ode

Step size controllers for ODE solvers with adaptive step size usually track an error estimate $y_{\mathrm{err}}$ and compare it to the current state $y_\mathrm{current}$ to decide if a step can be accepted or the step size needs to be decreased. We consider the case of multi-dimensional ODEs, so all $y$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. There seem to be two ways to do this comparison. The first checks if the norm of the ratios between error and some tolerable error scale is less than one, i.e.
$$
\left\|\frac{y_{\mathrm{err}}}{\mathrm{atol} + \mathrm{rtol} \cdot y_\mathrm{scale}}\right\| < 1
$$
where all operations are elementwise and $\left\|\cdot\right\|$ is some norm. $\mathrm{atol}$ and $\mathrm{rtol}$ are the absolute and relative tolerance, respectively, and $y_\mathrm{scale}$ is something like $\max(\operatorname{abs}(y_\mathrm{current}), \operatorname{abs}(y_\mathrm{next}))$. The advantage of this approach is some built-in scale invariance. If some components of $y$ live on a much smaller scale than others, these will cancel out and the components will be considered more evenly in the step acceptance decision. However, from a mathematical perspective, the formula above is quite nonsensical, because elementwise division of vectors is not a meaningful operation in normal vector spaces. Under the consideration of mathematical sensibility, it would make more sense to check for step acceptance using
$$
\frac{\left\|y_{\mathrm{err}}\right\|}{\mathrm{atol} + \mathrm{rtol} \cdot \left\|y_\mathrm{scale}\right\|} < 1.
$$
Now we are taking norms of vectors living in the same vector space that we are solving the equation in and building ratios of real numbers, all of which are well-defined. Nonetheless, I almost exclusively see the former approach in real code and not the latter, and I have to agree that the scale-invariance argument makes a lot of sense in practice.

Is there some theoretical argument to guide the decision on when to prefer one over the other?

---

For example, diffrax, a python ODE solver for the JAX framework, chooses norm of ratio as [described in their code](https://github.com/patrick-kidger/diffrax/blob/77bd28b03aafdebcd985d900118ffb900be66d65/diffrax/step_size_controller/adaptive.py#L388-L396).

Comment: The blind application of the vector norm variant leads to numerical instability in the smaller components as you describe. The element-wise approach just works, sometimes `atol` needs to be given as vector that reflects the global scale of the components. A middle way would be to have the model produce a norm list where the single norms combine components that are vectors in the model. For instance in a planetary model this would be norms of position and velocity for every body.

Comment: By the way, it is safer to use $atol +rtol|y|$  in the denominator to avoid the risk of it becoming zero when some components of $y$ are . Also the choice of the norm has a role. The 2-norm will "average" the errors, while the inf-norm will be more strict.

Comment: Think about what happens if the components of $y$ have different physical units, and which of the two ways you show makes sense.